# QGIS format_number with tailing zeros

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, format, numbering

I am working in a attribute table trying to format my numbers, but want to keep ending zeros. I am using `format_numbers("column",sig figs)`. For the most part, it is working, but for example row two in the picture below, I need to zero to show to have everything line up perfectly. I am working in QGIS 3.10.4.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: That is not the expected behavior of the `format_number` function and is solved in the most recent version of QGIS latest and LTR.

Comment: Do I need to reset my qgis project after the calculation?

Comment: You need to update your QGIS version to 3.10.9, before the calculation..

Comment: If you're using a numeric column, you will lose any leading and trailing zeros. If you want to keep them, you should store your data in a text/varchar column

Comment: Interesting, I would have thought that QGIS would have had another argument to keep tailing zeros. Ended up creating another column, setting it to text format, `format_number("NDVI_mean",5)`. That worked.

Comment: @DPSSpatial Is there a way to set that in zonal statistics so I don't have to change each column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you figured it out. For posterity, I would set up a separate string field and use the Attributes Form to automatically reformat the values from your numeric field:

[image: Attributes Form]

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Yes that works, but lets say I have 100 columns. I don't think anyone would want to reformat every column. Perhaps I could take it into R and reformat it there, then export it back in???

Comment: Yep, I'd say that sounds like a scripting exercise at that point.